# getting error "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" from my ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, session

I am developing an E-Commerce website using MERN stack. I want to display two different navbars based on the condition if the user is logged-in or not! and I have used `res.locals` in my app.js file to expose data to all templates but when I am using this data in my index.ejs file by `user.username`, its showing me above error.

I am stuck in this problem and have searched for this whole day but can't get any solution.

Here is my app.js file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

app.use(session({
    name: 'uid',
    secret: 'LoginSession',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        expires: 6000000
    }
}))

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.user = req.session.user;
    next();
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is my index.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <% include partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <% if (!user.username) { %>
        <% include partials/navhome %>
        <%} else { %>
            <% include partials/navhome1 %>
        <% } %>
    
    <div class="main-banner header-text" id="top">
        <div class="Modern-Slider">
            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item item-1" style="background-image: url(../images/slider-image-1-1920x900.jpg);">
                <div class="img-fill">
                    <div class="text-content">
                        <h6>New Arrival!</h6>
                        <h4>Iphone 12 Pro</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- // Item -->
            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item item-2" style="background-image: url(../images/slider-image-2-1920x900.jpg);">
                <div class="img-fill">
                    <div class="text-content">
                        <h6>New Arrival!</h6>
                        <h4>Samsung S21 Ultra 5G</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- // Item -->
            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item item-3" style="background-image: url(../images/slider-image-3-1920x900.jpg);">
                <div class="img-fill">
                    <div class="text-content">
                        <h6>New Arrival!</h6>
                        <h4>Oneplus 9 pro 5G</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- // Item -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Banner Ends Here -->

    <div class="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h2>Featured <em>Smart-Phones</em></h2>
                        <span>Phones with best prices and specifications</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <img src="./images/product-1-720x480.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="down-content">
                            <h4>Apple Iphone 7</h4>
                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <span>Rs </sup>35000.00 </span>
                            </div>

                            <p>The Iphone 7 attributes 4.7 inch screen, 12 MP back and 7 MP front camera. It comes with iOS 10.0.1 which is upgradable to iOS 11.2.5 and runs on 2.34GHz processor.</p>
                            <a href="product-details.html" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <img src="./images/product-2-720x480.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="down-content">
                            <h4>Realme 5 pro</h4>
                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <span>Rs </sup>32000.00 </span>
                            </div>

                            <p>The new Realme 5 Pro is packed with a powerful chipset and high-quality camera setup. The handset is powered by Snapdragon 712 chipset.</p>
                            <a href="product-details.html" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <img src="./images/product-3-720x480.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="down-content">
                            <h4>Apple Iphone 11 pro</h4>
                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <span>Rs </sup>254,600.00 </span>
                            </div>

                            <p>Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max is packed with high-end specs and will be the flagship of the series. The phone is powered by A13 chip.</p>
                            <a href="product-details.html" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <img src="./images/OnePlus-Nord.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="down-content">
                            <h4>One Plus Nord</h4>
                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <span>Rs </sup>54,500.00 </span>
                            </div>

                            <p>This device will be powered by one of the latest chipsets available for smartphones in the market that is called Qualcomm SM6350 Snapdragon 690 5G.</p>
                            <a href="product-details.html" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <img src="./images/SamsungGalaxyS20Ultra__1_.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="down-content">
                            <h4>Samsung Galaxy S20</h4>
                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <span>Rs </sup>170,999.00 </span>
                            </div>

                            <p>Samsung Galaxy S20's chipset is paired with 8 gigabytes of RAM. The high-end RAM and chipset will the processing speed of the smartphone very fast.</p>
                            <a href="product-details.html" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <img src="./images/huawei-p40-black.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="down-content">
                            <h4>Huawei P40 Pro</h4>
                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <span>Rs </sup>179,999.00 </span>
                            </div>

                            <p>P40 pro has 8 GB of RAM and Krin 990 powerfull processor. It supports wireless charging and equipped with 5500mAh battery capacity.</p>
                            <a href="product-details.html" class="filled-button">Shop Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fun-facts">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="more-info-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="left-image">
                            <img src="./images/about-1-570x350.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
                        <div class="right-content">
                            <h2>Get to know about <em>our shop</em></h2>
                            <p>Our shop is recognised as the world no 1 selling smart phone shop because we provides best deals and original products!</p>
                            <a href="about.html" class="filled-button">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonials">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h2>What they say <em>about us</em></h2>
                        <span>feedback from our greatest customers</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="owl-testimonials owl-carousel">

                        <div class="testimonial-item">
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <h4>George Walker</h4>
                                <span>Chief Financial Analyst</span>
                                <p>"Phone E-Shop provided us with the best smart phones in the market under best pricing"</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="testimonial-item">
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <h4>John Smith</h4>
                                <span>Market Specialist</span>
                                <p>"Phone E-Shop is the best store right now in smart phone industry which cares about the customer opinoin"</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer Starts Here -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 footer-item">
                    <h4>Phone E-Shop</h4>
                    <p>The store which have all smart phones that you are looking for!</p>
                    <ul class="social-icons">
                        <li><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.twiter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 footer-item">
                    <h4>Additional Pages</h4>
                    <ul class="menu-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Go to top</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 footer-item last-item">
                    <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                    <div class="contact-form">
                        <form id="contact footer-contact" action="" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required="">
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required="">
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <textarea name="message" rows="6" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" required=""></textarea>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="filled-button">Send Message</button>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <div class="sub-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Copyright © 2021 Phone E-Shop - All right reserved.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <% include partials/script %>

</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if anyone of you want any other file!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have just exposed your password to MongoDB Atlas. You should dump the whole instance right away.

Comment: Cool! Never use secrets in the actual code. Always use a .env file! :)

Comment: Not sure that’s why I haven’t posted an answer.. can you try to console.log the result of req.session.user on the middleware you use before declaring res.locals.user and see the result? It will probably be undefined and that’s where you can start investigating the issue..

Comment: @MattiaRasulo I have written this before declaring res.locals ``console.log(req.session.user);`` but it saying req is not defined!

Comment: Try moving the middleware after the users route!

Comment: @MattiaRasulo Tried but same issue. It is saying undefined again!

Comment: That’s weird, your express setup looks all right!

Comment: @MattiaRasulo Yes I am stuck :(